# What i am doing wrong with this loop?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
       for ( int i = printf("\nFor loop initialized ") , printf("Intialized value of i is %i", i) ;
            i >= printf("\nCondition checked") , printf("Current value of i is") ;
            printf("\nValue of i is decremented") , i-- )
       {
             printf(" %i", i);
       }

    printf("\nCondition false, Loop exited.");
       return 0;
}
```

following are the error given by `gcc -Wall -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`:

> ```
> 5:53: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
> 5:84: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'i'
> 5:88: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
> ```

what is `...` ?

According to me the output should be:

```
For loop initialized Intialized value of i is 21  
Condition checked Current value of i is 21  
Value of i is decremented  
Condition checked Current value of i is 20  
Value of i is decremented  
Condition checked Current value of i is 19  
Value of i is decremented  
Condition checked Current value of i is 18  
Value of i is decremented  
Condition checked  
Condition false, Loop exited.
```

Comment: Well, writing it in the first place was a bad plan:(

Comment: In `int i,n,q` the `,` is a comma operator, with sequence points? I actually don't use such initialization at all, so I don't know. :(

Comment: @2501: The comma operator has sequence points, but that is not a comma operator, but part of the declarator. Sorry, I forgot about operator preceedence. Anyway, that is rubbish code, why even bother?

Comment: @Olaf C11 says that there is a sequence point and evaluation is in order they appear, so from left to right. It seems int i = x++,j=x++; is defined an always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first section of the for loop can only hold declarations, and a call to printf is not a declaration. You can call printf from a second declaration. Also it's not necessary to have the entire thing on a single line.

```
  for(int i=printf("\nFor loop initialized "), 
          j=printf("Intialized value of i is %i", i);

      i>=printf("\nCondition checked") && printf("Current value of i is");

      printf("\nValue of i is decremented"), i--)
```

Comment: I don't see any way for you to specify a stopping condition. Therfore you can only expect an infinite loop.

Comment: In first section, i=21, and in second section i>=18 (i.e. 21>=18), in third section i is decremented, so i should have gone below 18 at some point.

Comment: what you are saying, i am getting as 21>=21 then i is decremented so in the next pass 20>=21 (Condition false, Loop exited.)

Comment: That's because the comma operator has a lower precedence than the comparison, so  `i > 18, 21` will return 21, no matter what's in `i`... many ways to fix that, using AND rather than comma operator is one, see update

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what's going on here:

1. The version of C you're using doesn't allow declarations inside a `for` loop.
2. C99 does allow such declarations, but with C99 the `printf` after the initialization of `i` is causing a syntax error since it's not another declaration.
3. The reason the loop is infinite is because of the comma operator after the comparison, causing the value of the loop continuation expression to be the result of the `printf` that follows the comparison, which is always non-zero.

Answer (score -1):

`...` referred as variable argument in 'C' Language. If you want to pass multiple arguments to a string which is not defined, (i.e) the function may take any no of argument at ant time that time we use variable argument list.

Ex:

```
void myFunc(...)
```

Here myFunc can take multiple arguments
You can refer to the below URL for better understanding.

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm
```

Hope This Clears your doubt in some way.